# Is every point of rational number boundary point?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory

While studying first chapter of multivariable calculus, I am wondering if every point of the rational number is boundary point.

It is obvious that $\Bbb{R}^n$ is the union of interior, exterior, boundary of $S$, $S$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$.  For $S$ subset of $\Bbb{Q}$, I know that there is no interior nor exterior point, does that mean that every point of $S$ is boundary point of $S$?

Comment: Lots of confusing usage of terms here. A boundary point of what? What do you mean by "It is obvious that R^n is union of interior, exterior, boundary of S, S is a subset of R?" What is $S$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathbb Q^n \subset \mathbb R^n$ the subset. We know that "boundary = closure - interior". We know the subset is dense, i.e. closure = everything. We see easily that interior is empty, for if we take a point in the rationals, every neighborhood will intersect the irrationals. Hence "closure - interior = all - nothing = boundary = $\mathbb R^n\subset \mathbb R^n $ . In particular every point is a boundary point.